Cannot login with wayland on 23.10
So until today I've been able to login OK with Wayland, but now I'm encountering the login screen loop issue whereby entering my password is accepted but I'm then taken straight back to the login screen.
Things I've  tried:

Creating a new user and logging in as that user, which works fine

Temporarily moving the following ~/ folders,.local, .cache, .config

Moving ~/.Xauthority temporarily

Editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and adding WaylandEnable=false, which also works fine but isn't ideal as some of my applications depend on Wayland

I've also checked ~/.xsession-errors, but there aren't any obvious error messages. Here are the last few lines:



Xsession: X session started for ian at Thu Apr 18 02:57:12 PM BST 2024
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/ian/.Xauthority
localuser:ian being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1


What else should I be checking to diagnose and fix this?
Edit:
Added tail output of LANG=C journalctl --no-pager -n100 -xu gdm.service as requested.
Apr 18 21:04:30 ian-Latitude-3350 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Deactivated successfully.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit gdm.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state. Apr 18 21:04:30 ian-Latitude-3350 systemd[1]: Stopped gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit gdm.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit gdm.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 4273 and the job result is done.
-- Boot 26a971f691854edb922658ab7473af74 -- Apr 18 21:04:58 ian-Latitude-3350 systemd[1]: Starting gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager...
-- Subject: A start job for unit gdm.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit gdm.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 239. Apr 18 21:04:58 ian-Latitude-3350 systemd[1]: Started gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit gdm.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit gdm.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 239. Apr 18 21:04:59 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-launch-environment][2075]: pam_env(gdm-launch-environment:session): deprecated reading of user environment enabled Apr 18 21:04:59 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-launch-environment][2075]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=123) by (uid=0) Apr 18 21:05:25 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][2942]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file Apr 18 21:05:25 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][2942]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session Apr 18 21:05:25 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][2942]: pam_env(gdm-password:session): deprecated reading of user environment enabled Apr 18 21:05:25 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][2942]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user ian(uid=1000) by (uid=0) Apr 18 21:05:26 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][2942]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring Apr 18 21:05:33 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm3[2030]: Gdm: Child process -2172 was already dead. Apr 18 21:06:56 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-launch-environment][4432]: pam_env(gdm-launch-environment:session): deprecated reading of user environment enabled Apr 18 21:06:56 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-launch-environment][4432]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=123) by (uid=0) Apr 18 21:09:01 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][5283]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file Apr 18 21:09:01 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][5283]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session Apr 18 21:09:01 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][5283]: pam_env(gdm-password:session): deprecated reading of user environment enabled Apr 18 21:09:01 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][5283]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user ian(uid=1000) by (uid=0) Apr 18 21:09:01 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm-password][5283]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring Apr 18 21:09:07 ian-Latitude-3350 gdm3[2030]: Gdm: Child process -4455 was already dead.

Edit:
Adding output of journalctl | grep -P 'gnome-shell\[[0-9]+\]' | tail -n100:

Apr 19 11:05:02 ian-Latitude-3350 gnome-shell[2407]: JS ERROR: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available


Apr 19 11:05:06 ian-Latitude-3350 gnome-shell[5473]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 45.2) as a Wayland display server


Apr 19 11:05:06 ian-Latitude-3350 gnome-shell[5473]: Failed to setup: Could not take control: GDBus.Error:System.Error.EBUSY: Device or resource busy


Apr 19 11:05:08 ian-Latitude-3350 gnome-shell[2407]: JS ERROR: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available


Apr 19 11:05:08 ian-Latitude-3350 gnome-shell[2407]: JS ERROR: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Set global engine failed: Operation was cancelled


Can you post the output of LANG=C journalctl --no-pager -n100 -xu gdm.service?

@kos Hi, I've added the output in an edit. The formatting's a bit messed up, but the content is there.

Hm I'd check journalctl | grep -P 'gnome-shell\[[0-9]+\]' | tail -n100 for errors, have you tried just reinstalling gnome-shell?

@kos I've added that output. reinstalling gnome-shell had no effect.

I looked up the most damning error, it appears it could be related to an extension: someone on the Arch Linux Forums managed to solve it by doing this
